# Is there a way to determine if the same file was submitted more than once to a list?

Tags: custom-list, attachments

"New" hire SharePoint developer (~8 months in) and the senior developer has moved to another agency. I subsequently inherited a variety of SharePoint applications. I recently had a request from the customer of one of them for, so I will do my best to describe the workings and why they requested.

The application uses a set of specialized InfoPath forms and workflows.
The image below shows the main InfoPath form. 
[image: main InfoPath form]

When the client is using it, they fill out the form and attach a file the gets sent out to be worked on. After the form is submitted, it essentially is stored within a custom list. The customer came to me with the following:

> "A dialog box pops up to let the counselor know their tape was submitted successfully.   However, that does not prevent someone from uploading their tape more than once.  I believe Windows assigns a number to an audio file, and since SharePoint is part of Microsoft and Windows compatible, is there a way to incorporate this identifier to be able to determine if the same tape was submitted more than once?"

What is this unique number assign? (I'm thinking SharePoint assigns all items a unique identifier when uploaded) And is it possible to force uniqueness, so when a file is uploaded, it cannot be uploaded again?

Comment: Have you done it by code or rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are submitting these files as attachments to a custom list, then it is not simple or easy to determine if the attachment is unique at the time they submit.

However, [a simple out of the box system is to enforce your `Title` column](http://referpages.com/wp/2011/02/sharepoint-2010-enforce-unique-column-values/)  value to be unique.  ([or any multiple columns](https://salnikan.wordpress.com/2011/07/26/prevention-of-duplicate-entries-based-on-two-or-more-columns-in-a-sharepoint-list/)).  So you should encourage your customer to come up with specific instructions to your client's needs.  This will force the users to put in unique column values when they are uploading attachments.

Do the tapes have unique serial numbers?  or are they tapes of a unique subject which has an identifier?  Season 6 Episode 4 for example.  You should encourage your customer to come up with the [business rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_rule) and you model the rules in column(s) with unique values to enforce the business rules.  Otherwise a complex coded solution will take time and be a point of maintenance for you and the next developer to worry about.

Comment: Looking across tape names, there doesn't appear to be any consistent naming convention though. the "tapes" are an audio file that is uploaded (generally a .wma file) All the tapes are recordings of interviews.

They do have a naming convention for the Title. so that could be a good avenue to go toward with forcing unique values.

Comment: @TimeStamp12 - If the Title naming convention is too complex to model with one or more columns, a simple way to enforce it onto the users is to add it as the column description.  Then in your InfoPath form, make sure the description is displayed under the input box for the Title to remind users how to follow the naming convention.  For exmaple  **Please use naming convention** _LastName-MMDDYYYY-Region-SerialNumber_ **to avoid duplicates.  Failure to will result in delayed reimbuirsement** or something similar.  Let the customer define the naming convention and you reinforce it with the form.

Comment: The naming convention that's already in place is pretty consistent as FiscalYear-Number. So a recent one is 2016-663, followed 2016-664. So I think title enforcement would be useful. Though, I'm not sure if there is a naming convention for storing tapes on their side for upload. Unless the idea was if submitting a new tape entry, a previously uploaded tape is accidently selected as the attachment. That might need to be more addressed on the client side for organization then.